# Adding recursive functionality to a json merge script in php

Tags: php

How do I recursively access all json files?

The below code finds all the json files in a single directory and merges them into a single file.
I now have a hierarchical folder structure, how do I adapt the following to cycle through all the directories under the root directory `json/bones`?

```
<?php
    $files = glob("json/bones/*.json");
    //Create an empty new array
    $newDataArray = [];
    //Get the contents of each file
    foreach($files as $file){
        $thisData = file_get_contents($file);
        //Decode the json
        $thisDataArray = json_decode($thisData);
        //Add $thisData to the new array
        $newDataArray[] = $thisDataArray;
    }
    //Encode the array to JSON
    $newDataJSON = json_encode($newDataArray);
    file_put_contents("json/data.json",$newDataJSON);
?>
```

edit - new code:

```
<?php
    $directory = ("json/data/")
    $scan_dir = scandir ( string $directory [, int $sorting_order = SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING [, resource $context ]] ) : array;
      //Create an empty new array


    $newDataArray = [];
    //Get the contents of each file
    // foreach($files as $file){
    foreach($scan_dir as $file){
       $thisData = file_get_contents($file);
        //Decode the json
        $thisDataArray = json_decode($thisData);
        //Add $thisData to the new array
        $newDataArray[] = $thisDataArray;
    }
    //Encode the array to JSON
    $newDataJSON = json_encode($newDataArray);
    file_put_contents("json/data.json",$newDataJSON);
?>
```

Further edit:

This now presents a permissions error `file_get_contents(.): failed to open stream: Permission denied` it had no issues before.

```
<?php
  $dir = "../../json/data/";
  echo "<p>directory: ".$dir."</p>";
  $files = scandir($dir);
  //Create an empty new array
  $newDataArray = [];
  //Get the contents of each file
  // foreach($files as $file){
  foreach($files as $file){
      $thisData = file_get_contents($file);
      //Decode the json
      $thisDataArray = json_decode($thisData);
      //Add $thisData to the new array
      $newDataArray[] = $thisDataArray;
  }
  //Encode the array to JSON
  $newDataJSON = json_encode($newDataArray);
  file_put_contents("data.json",$newDataJSON);
?>
```

Comment: [recursively fetch all files - source: php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php#107117) might be useful.

Comment: So to get an array of file paths:

$directory = ("json/bones/")


$scan_dir = scandir ( string $directory [, int $sorting_order = SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING [, resource $context ]] ) : array

Comment: Then would `foreach($scan_dir as $file){` pick up all files, then I'd have to add a filter?

Comment: I'm getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$scan_dir' (T_VARIABLE) in G:\Drive\servers\xampp\htdocs\bonify\bonify2_0_2\app\settings\edit\get_json.php on line 5` I'll add the new code in an edit.

Comment: Use the RecursiveDirectoryIterator provided by the spl https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php#97228

Comment: The gives `Warning: file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given`

Comment: another edit added

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick

```
$rii = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('../../json/data/'));

$files = array();

foreach ($rii as $file) {
    if ($file->isDir()){
        continue;
    }
    $files[] = $file->getPathname();
}

var_dump($files);



  // $dir = "../../json/data/";
  // echo "<p>directory: ".$dir."</p>";
  // $files = scandir($dir);
  //Create an empty new array
  $newDataArray = [];
  //Get the contents of each file
  // foreach($files as $file){
  foreach($files as $file){
      $thisData = file_get_contents($file);
      //Decode the json
      $thisDataArray = json_decode($thisData);
      //Add $thisData to the new array
      $newDataArray[] = $thisDataArray;
  }
  //Encode the array to JSON
  $newDataJSON = json_encode($newDataArray);
  file_put_contents("gfgdata.json",$newDataJSON);
```